# Question about the derivative of $x \mapsto \langle x , x \rangle $ (Scalar product)

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

$f: x \mapsto \langle   x , x \rangle $

In my book it says that $f'(x)=\langle 2x, \rangle$. I'm aware that $f: X \to \mathbb R$, what is not clear is this result. Can anyone explain how it comes to be?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at $f(x+h)$ and see that
$$f(x+h) = \langle x+h,x+h \rangle=\langle x,x \rangle + \langle 2x,h \rangle + \langle h,h \rangle = f(x) + \langle 2x,h \rangle +o(h).$$
This shows that $f^{\prime}(x)=2x.$